# Android - View, Checkboxes, TextViews not refreshing at Runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, refresh

I'm new to Android, and I'm having a problem with checkboxes and textviews not refreshing at runtime. The TextView has to change color from light gray to a lighter gray, and the Checkbox has to change the custom drawable that it has from red to green. I have tried the detach and attach the fragment but it shuts down and maybe I don't know where to put the detach and attach in the fragment. I have tried invalidate() and requestLayout(), and it shuts down there too. I tried having them in onCreateView() and maybe I shouldn't put them there. I don't have an activity with my fragment. Here are the images that I need to change. What it has in the preview window is the green custom checkbox drawables but at runtime they are the red custom drawables which is what they were before I changed them to green, and the TextViews are a lighter gray in the preview window but they are a darker gray at Runtime which is what they were before.

[image: Green checkbox custom drawable] [image: Red custom custom drawable]

```
public class CheckListFragment extends Fragment{
   private RelativeLayout fragment_checklist;
   private Fragment fragment = new CheckListFragment();
   private Checkbox chkStart, chkDownload;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checklist, container, false);
   fragment_checklist = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_checklist_gather);

    chkStart = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chkStarted);
    chkDownload = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chkDownloaded);

    //tried to explicitly make it green but doesn't work.
    chkStart.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_green_checkbox);
    chkDownload.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_green_checkbox);

    fragment.getView().invalidate(); // tried these
    fragment.getView().requestLayout();// tried these

    //tried this. Maybe in the wrong spot.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(fragment);
    ft.attach(fragment);
    ft.commit();

    return rootView;
   }
}
<RelativeLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkStarted"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chkInProgess"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:button="@xml/custom_checkbox_green"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkDownloaded"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chkStarted"
            android:text="@string/download"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:button="@xml/custom_checkbox_green"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

The textviews are not changing colors either at runtime, and I have tried to refresh the layouts, but they're not refreshing at runtime. They are what they need to be in the preview window, but they are not what they're supposed to be at runtime. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are setting in code `custom_green_checkbox` as opposed to `custom_checkbox_green` in the xml.  Java will override the xml background. Check if those two are the same files.

Comment: also one of them is in drawable folder and the other one in xml

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had read on some other stackoverflow pages that they set their textview to not visible and then visible. That didn't work for me, but I figured out that setting the checkboxes to unchecked and then checked again fixed it in the onCreateView.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checklist, container, false);

    chkStart = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chkStarted);
    chkDownload = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chkDownloaded);

    chkStart.setChecked(false);
    chkStart.setChecked(true);
    chkDownload.setChecked(false);
    chkDownload.setChecked(true);

    return rootView;
}
```

The problem was the checkboxes were already checked and that meant they were red and for it to appear green, it had to be unchecked then checked again. Also, I had other code that made it appear green. So, that was my solution.